# Does chip size affect accuracy while training the image in semantic segmentation using UNet?

Tags: neural-networks, accuracy, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am working on a UNet model with backbone set to ResNet34.

My data is high resolution (7.5 centimeter) satellite imagery. Currently I am processing my data on my laptop, hence I cannot create a chipset of satellite imagery more than 256 x 256. If I do so, my laptop's GPU memory gets exhausted, resulting in an error.

With my current configuration of 256 x 256 I am not getting good results from the model, however the accuracy after training I get is 95 percent.

Hence could the chip size be an issue? Would changing the chipsize to 500 x 500 make any difference?